# Modify all but first element of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say there is this array of arrays:

```
theArray = [["name1", 12.23423, 54.243, 6.23566, 5675.552, ...],
            ["name2", 345.8655, 92.9316, ..],
            ["name3", 99.56756, 52.988, 3.09889, ...],
            ...
            ];
```

Each sub-array starts with a string and it is followed by numbers. My aim is to reduce the numbers to a shorter form.

I know that this can be done using `.toFixed(2)` in order to have only two digits after the dot by I don't know how to access them because of the string in the front.

I want them to remain as numbers because I must use them as data for a chart.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you get a string after using `toFixed` ...? do you like to get a number or a string?

Comment: Do you want them to remain as numbers?

Comment: just use two nested for loops. the first with index 0 the second with index 1

Comment: I want them to remain as numbers because I must use them as data for a chart.

Comment: See the dupe target for the rounding. You'll need to check if the index is greater than `0`, before rounding. Or check if the value is a `number` or a `string`.

Comment: Reopen voters: I've added a dupe target about skipping a specific index. Please retract your re-open votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the value of the first item.

```js
var array = [["name1", 12.23423, 54.243, 6.23566, 5675.552], ["name2", 345.8655, 92.9316], ["name3", 99.56756, 52.988, 3.09889]],
    result = array.map(a => a.map((v, i) => i ? +v.toFixed(2) : v));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution by just using two nested for loops with Index 0 and Index 1.

```
theArray = [["name1", 12.23423, 54.243, 6.23566, 5675.552],
           ["name2", 345.8655, 92.9316],
           ["name3", 99.56756, 52.988, 3.09889],
           ];


for(var i=0;i<theArray.length;i++) {
  for(var k=1;k<theArray[i].length;k++) {
    theArray[i][k] = parseFloat(theArray[i][k].toFixed(2));
  }
}
console.log(theArray);
```

Comment: converts numbers to strings

Comment: correct. i edited my post.